# Is it okay for my employer to make me disclose my medical history (in the last five years..) under a “fit for work” form?

Tags: legal, netherlands

I work in the Netherlands as a consultant for a company. The client I am consulting for has sent me a “Fit for Work” assessment that I have to fill out which asks me to disclose all medical concerns I have had within the last 5 years, whether I have received treatment for them and if it restricts me from carrying out my work. These questions include if I've had breathing or respiratory issues, ear/nose/throat or eye problems and even psychological disorders to name a few.

They also ask if I have ever been rejected from employment on medical grounds. They claim it is mandatory to fill out. Is this allowed?

I do not feel comfortable sharing this much information, considering I just work as an analyst and most of this does not affect my work.

Comment: That would probably be super illegal, unless there is a specific reason for it. What kind of work is it, do medical conditions play a part or is it a normal desk job? For example, will you be in a very dusty or claustrophobic environment, that the employer might even be legally required to make sure it is not a health risk to you?

Comment: I work a hybrid desk job that definitely does not take place in a claustrophobic environment

Comment: That sounds considerably out of bounds. I suggest contacting your own HR department for advice. If this is indeed illegal (which is likely) your own company has a legal exposure risk and it's in their best interest to not step in this. Who owns the business relationship/contract with the client ? That person should also be involved. You may want to check what the contract says.

Comment: You could "pad"out the submission with lots of severely embarrassing treatments and procedures with plenty of detail... And would they get access to your REAL records? I have 2 medical professionals in the family who would help with this :)

Comment: If it was me, I would just answer "I have no concerns" to everything.  If there was reason for concern that comes up later, the first question to ask is was it legal for them to even ask?  The burden of proof is on them not you.

Answer (score 15):

So, the Netherlands would come under EU - so GDPR is a factor here.

I am not a Lawyer - however a quick read of the relevant bits and pieces around it would seem to indicate:

- An employer can *request* any medical information from an employee
- An employee can *decline* consent for said medical information
- Consent in the above is defined as 'with no negative consequences'
- EU law, however, does allow an employer with *reasonable* grounds to request medical information where failure to comply would result in negative consequences.
- An example given was a Nurse who worked in Pediatrics, contracted HIV - they had a duty to inform their employer which resulted in them being re-assigned to a different department.

So - the question is - why have they requested this information? If there is a reasonable work-related reason - then the Employer can ask, you can decline and they can decide to stop their professional engagement with you.

If it's not a reasonable work-related reason - then they can still ask, you can decline and if they take action against you, you have legal recourse.

However, bearing in mind, without a court judgement on your *specific* set of circumstances, it isn't 100% possible to confirm that the Why is valid or not valid. A good rule of thumb though is that if the business can give a reason as to why a certain health condition might impact your ability to do a job (Our HIV Nurse working with babies whose immune systems aren't fully developed or may be compromised is a good example) - then it's likely all above board.

Comment: I think this severely overrepresents what EU employers can reasonably ask their employees. For a desk job the general understanding is that the employer can ask no health questions whatsoever. If an employee thinks they have health issues for a deskjob that the employer can provide accomodation for then the employee can inform the employer. If an employer wants to ask health questions they need some very good very specific reasons. For a typical consulting position I would assume just asking is already too much.

Comment: @quarague - from what I read and if you look at the answer Mark Rotteveel - the employer can/may ask, but they are only entitled to an answer in certain circumstances. Nowhere did it say it was illegal to ask - buy yes, I would agree with the sentiment that it's improper, absent a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

Requests for such information by an employer is absolutely not normal in my experience, but I don't know whether it is legally allowed or not (FYI: I have lived and worked in The Netherlands all my life), but based on the articles I link below, I would say it is very likely not legal. Even more so because it is not even your own employer, but a third-party who wants to know. You don't have a contractual relationship with that third-party. You only have a contractual relationship with your employer, not that third-party, and even your employer is not allowed to know that information, and cannot force your to disclose such information (see below).

Employers can ask if you're physically able to do certain work, but only if it is actually relevant for the work that you'll perform. However, for such questions a yes or no answer, and/or mentioning specific limitations or accommodations should be acceptable without actual medical details.

The normal way of working in The Netherlands would be that the company doctor (bedrijfsarts/ARBO-arts, a medical doctor either employed by the company or hired through a third-party) would asses medical things like this and only communicate the bare minimum to the employer (e.g. OK to work, or not OK to work, or what adjustments are needed or what limitations apply or accommodations are needed). The company doctor has the same doctor/patient confidentiality rules as a normal doctor.

In this case, because it's between your employer and a client, I would guess that the company doctor of the client should consult the company doctor of your employer, and your company doctor would then do an assessment with you. The company doctor of your employer could probably also inform you whether the request by the client is actually normal or allowed.

Even if you're not sick, you can normally get an appointment with a company doctor through the HR department of your employer (or they can provide you with the contact information to make the appointment yourself).

For more information, [this article](https://wsadvocaten.nl/mag-mijn-werkgever-mijn-medische-gegevens-vragen/) (from a Dutch law firm) says:

> Een werkgever moet de privacy van de medewerker respecteren volgens
> artikel 10 van de Grondwet en de Wet Bescherming Persoonsgegevens; en
> heeft dus geen recht op verstrekking van medische gegevens. De
> werkgever mag in het kader van het arbeidsrecht hoogstens vragen of,
> in geval van ziekte, de ziekte verband houdt met een arbeidsongeval of
> verkeersongeval. De werkgever mag ook controleren of een medewerker
> die verzuimt hiervoor een geldige reden heeft maar mag niet informeren
> naar de aard en de oorzaak van de ziekte. Dat geldt ook voor
> niet-medici zoals de casemanager, verzuimconsulent of de
> personeelsfunctionaris.

Translated (with help of Google Translate):

> An employer must respect the employee's privacy according to Article
> 10 of the Constitution and the Personal Data Protection Act; and is
> therefore not entitled to the provision of medical data. In the
> context of labor law, the employer may at most ask whether, in the
> event of illness, the illness is related to an industrial accident or
> traffic accident. The employer may also check whether an employee who
> is absent has a valid reason for this, but may not inquire about the
> nature and cause of the illness. This also applies to non-medical
> professionals such as the case manager, absenteeism consultant or
> human resources officer.

That said, the article is specifically about a case involving sick leave, so it might not cover all relevant situations.

In some cases a health assessment may be legally required for work, but this must follow "de Wet op de Medische Keuringen" (Medical Examinations Act), and although I've not read this law, I guess this has the requirements that it is performed by a medical doctor, and only the conclusion (e.g. fit for work/not fit for work) to be communicated to the employer/company.

Another interesting article is [this one](https://privacy-web.nl/artikelen/de-verwerking-van-medische-gegevens-in-de-arbeidsrelatie), which basically states that employers are not legally allowed to process medical information:

> Daarnaast geldt de regel dat gezondheidsgegevens alleen mogen worden
> gebruikt door iemand die een verplichting heeft tot beroepsgeheim,
> zoals een (bedrijfs)arts. De werkgever mag dus zelf geen toegang
> hebben tot de gezondheidsgegevens van de werknemers.

Translated:

> In addition, the rule applies that health data may only be used by
> someone who has an obligation of professional secrecy, such as a
> (company) doctor. The employer may therefore not have access to the
> health data of the employees.

This article also states that although in theory you could "consent" by giving the information of your own free will, this legally does not hold water in an employee-employer relationship, because courts have ruled that there is at minimum an implicit coercion (or worse: explicit coercion) in such relationship which means it is questionable whether or not that consent is really freely given.

[Another article](https://kennisbank.patientenfederatie.nl/app/answers/detail/a_id/1281/%7E/werkgever-vraagt-medische-informatie) states:

> Een werkgever mag alleen vragen naar waar je tegenaan loopt in het
> werk. Bijvoorbeeld of je jouw werk wel zittend maar niet staand kunt
> doen. De werkgever mag geen vragen stellen over de medische oorzaak.
> Of over jouw medisch dossier. Wanneer je duidelijk aangeeft wat je
> nodig hebt om jouw werk zo goed mogelijk te doen, kan jouw werkgever
> hier rekening mee houden en je ondersteunen.

Translated:

> An employer may only ask about what you encounter at work. For
> example, whether you can do your work sitting but not standing. The
> employer may not ask questions about the medical cause. Or about your
> medical file. If you clearly indicate what you need to do your job as
> best as possible, your employer can take this into account and support
> you.

Answer (score 1):

While there are obvious circumstances (like working in medical/pharma/health-care/day-care/nursery, especially directly with patients/persons or in the production line - think FDA and the like) where the processing of health data by employers may be lawful and/or even obliged by law, employers must still comply with the principles and conditions set out in the GDPR.

Those solely rely on the explicit, informed, and unambiguous consent of the employee of said processing/storing their health data (which obviously opens another can or worms in terms of data-sec-issues, confidentiality and the like).

> I do not feel comfortable sharing this much information, considering I just work as an analyst and most of this does not affect my work.

Under your circumstances you have no obligation to provide your medical history and you shouldn't (IMO). If they say it's mandatory I'd play the 'Better Call Saul' card.

But keep in mind that they might not try to snoop into your medical history to filter you out  - there's also the chance that they might want to know if they can provide specififc accommodation if needed (in an ideal world of course).

Answer (score 1):

You are not obligated to share any personal information you choose not too.

But, logically, employer may ask for medical fitness to a position you are recruited for, according to job description.

For example: back hernia should be disclosed for delivery driver or furniture mover, but is not relevant for call center employee

Comment: The back hernia itself doesn't need to be disclosed to an employer, just that you're not able to do heavy lifting (or what the maximum weight is that you're allowed to lift).